# Efficient GraphFrame for different types of vertices

Tags: apache-spark, graphframes

I need to create a graphframe in spark databricks which will have 2 types of vertices lets say N1 and N2 with different properties.
Currently I am creating a new dataframe with all columns from both N1 and N2 with relevant values as given and rest values as NULL and using that dataframe to create graphframe.
Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I don't think there is a better way yet..
https://forums.databricks.com/questions/7792/with-graphframes-are-there-ways-of-dealing-with-mu.html
https://github.com/graphframes/graphframes/issues/181

Comment: @sopho-saksham did you find any alternative, I am also looking for similar use case